# Leaderboard function

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, leaderboard

I know nothing about the way the site works etc., but how cool and convenient would it be to have a simple wrapper to add a leaderboard for the question, like [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/59192) and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58974/levenshtein-distance-bias)? That functionality would really great for users on the site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Leaderboards are often custom-made to fit the requirements of a challenge, so it doesn't make sense for there to be a single function to accomplish this task.

Martin Büttner made a [leaderboard template](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet) that you can copy and paste into challenges though.

Comment: Disagree. [tag:code-golf] is most popular tag, and Martin's snippet now is de-facto standard. One-click leaderboard attachment is good.

Answer (score 1):

## Useful feature

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is most popular tag, and have [leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet) designed for it.

Snippet can be patched to fit [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) and [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining)

### Pluses

- One-click addition to challanges. No need to do it manually
- Snippet updates automatically applies to all challanges.

### Minuses

- Platform modification needed

### Demo

[image: demo]