# Sorting answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers

Some popular challenges have many many answers and often a language is used more than once, so :

Is there a way to sort answers so that they appear in the order according to the name of a language OR just answers written in a specific language ?

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate, because I can't find a proposal for alphabetic sorting in the linked question. And here, given that almost all answers start with the language name, it's nothing but a simple alphabetic sorting. However, the accepted answer remains true: No other site is likely to benefit from that option. So leave it declined, but reopen it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There unfortunately isn't a built-in way to sort or filter by language. It's a [feature we'd like to have](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8358/20260), but's it's surely too niche for Stack Exchange to implement.

That said, we have some workarounds. You can edit the [leaderboard snippet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5139/20260) into a challenge (or ask someone to), and running it shows the winner for each language. You could also install the [PPCG redesign userscript](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design), which includes an automatic leaderboard.

Comment: As this question reopens, I wonder if this answer should be the accepted answer.